# How to filter data and show in flatList (search flatlist) React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to search data and send that data to a flat list. The current code works without error however it only finds results with the an exact text searched. I am trying to filter data to give me results as long as the text that I am searching is found anywhere in the string. I need help with my handleSearch function

Example.
When I search: "Good book". it finds results.
If I search: "is a good book" I do not get any results

I would like to receive results for my string as long as the text is founded somewhere in the string

Example What I am hoping for. Find results if string contains:
This is a Good book, or
Good is a book.

```
// _.filter is a function I am using from Lodash
// action list is the data coming from another file: ActionListService.getList()
const ActionList = [
  {
    title: 'Good Book',
    icon: 'good book',
    action: 'good book',
  },
  {
    title: 'Hello World',
    icon: 'hello',
    action: 'hello action',
  },
]

const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [fullData, setFullData] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    ActionListService.getList()
      .then(results => {
        setData(results);
        setFullData(results);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleSearch = text => {
    const formattedQuery = text.toLowerCase();
    const filteredData = _.filter(fullData, value => {
      return value.title.toLowerCase().includes(formattedQuery);
    });
    setData(filteredData);
    setQuery(text);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Searchbar
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={queryText => handleSearch(queryText)}
        value={query}
      />
      <View style={{paddingLeft: insets.left, paddingRight: insets.right}}>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          numColumns={orientation.orientation ? 1 : 3}
          key={orientation.orientation ? 1 : 3}
          keyExtractor={item => item.title}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <List.Item
              onPress={() => createAction(item.action)}
              // eslint-disable-next-line react-native/no-inline-styles
              style={{
                width: orientation.orientation ? '100%' : '30%',
              }}
              title={item.title}
              left={() => <List.Icon icon={item.icon} />}
            />
          )}
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using the `lodash` library? JavaScript also has its own `filter()` method that you can use for this specific problem

Comment: No reason at all. I can change that. If I do will that solve my issue or would I still need to change other things?

Comment: I would recommend using the native `filter()` method if you are only using `lodash` for this specific problem. In order to solve your stated problem, you could do the following: `const filteredData = ActionList.filter(entry => formattedQuery.includes(entry.title.toLowerCase()))` This would match the first entry on "is a good book". However, this solution only works if the `formattedQuery` string contains the entire `title` property